# Download zip from geoserver using javascript

Tags: geoserver, javascript, wfs

How can i download zip file, made by geoserver WFS request, implemented in javascript? i'm using OpenLayers.Request.POST to send request.

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want here. Can you try to expand your question to a few paragraphs, perhaps showing what you're actually sending, what results you get, and what you expect to happen instead?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hidden form to realize that:

Button to start the Download:

```
    <input type="button" value="Download Layer Streams as Shapefile (ZIP)" 
     onclick="shapedownload('og:streams')">
```

Function to be called:

```
function shapedownload(layername) {

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?";

    // set options here

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "request";
    input.value = "GetFeature";
    form.appendChild(input);

    // repeat the above 5 lines for all parameters

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "service";
    input.value = "WFS";
    form.appendChild(input);


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "version";
    input.value = "1.0.0";
    form.appendChild(input);


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "outputFormat"
    input.value = "shape-zip";
    form.appendChild(input);


    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "typeName";
    // input.value="og:archsites";  // static layername replaced by parameter
    input.value = layername;
    form.appendChild(input);


    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();

    //  see http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2011-July/021473.html 

}
```

It's not incredibly elegant code but it works ;)

If you change the parameter with which you want to call the function you can 
download different layers, for example replace 'og:streams' with 'og:roads'.

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/vjasu3k8/